# Colour cells with a date more than 20 years ago?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a nominal roll with the birth dates of individuals. I need to create a program that will highlight the cells of birthdays that are more than 27 years ago in red, as 27 is the age limit. Could somebody help me with this? I know it's possible with conditional formatting function on Excel but I want to do it with vba so I can filter many different categories at once.

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service you will need to show what you already have tried (e.g. your code) and ask a *specific* question to your code where you got stuck. Also read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) to understand why you receive down votes on your question. You can [edit] your question to improve it and add what you already did.

Answer (score 0):

For formatting condition, you may use the following:

```
   'for whole column A, if cell value is greater than 27
    With Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, "=27")

      'color interior with red and black for font
      .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With
```

For the birth year, you may use the following function:

```
    '=YearDiff(B1) <- enter this on cells as a formula with birthday parameter (from B1 on this example)
    Function YearDiff(pDate As Date) As Long
      YearDiff = DateDiff("yyyy", pDate, Now())
    End Function
```

Next time, please exert effort to post your code so that we may see where you got stuck.